# Homomorphism given by a multiplication by an integer matrix A

Tags: abstract-algebra, matrices, ring-homomorphism

I have the following exercise.

Consider a homomorphism given by a multiplication by an integer matrix $A$ given by $\varphi : \mathbb{Z}^k \to \mathbb{Z}^k$. I have to prove that the image of $\varphi$ is of finite index if and only if $A$ is non-singular and the index is equal to $|\det(A)|$.

My attempt:

- "$\rightarrow$" $\operatorname{Im}(\varphi)$ is a subgroup of $\mathbb{Z}^k$ so since $\mathbb{Z}^k$ is abelian the index of the group is equal to $|\mathbb{Z}^k/\operatorname{Im}(\varphi)|=n$ with $n$ a natural number. Now I can say that, using Artin´s interpretation, $A=Q^{-1}A'P$. So $A'=QAP^{-1}$ where $A'$ is a diagonal matrix and $d_i$ with $i \in \{1, \ldots, r\}$ is a diagonal entry in row $i$ of $A'$ and $di|dj$ for each k>=j>i followed by, eventually, $k-r$ zeros. The next step is to write down $\mathbb{Z}^k/\operatorname{Im}(\varphi)=\mathbb{Z}^k/A\mathbb{Z}^k$ because I know this is true from the hypothesis. I'm getting stuck here, I don't know how could I follow. Another problem is that could possibly exist $k-r$ rows full of zeros of $A'$. Am I on the right track?

Any comment would be appreciated!

Comment: Do any of these answer your question? [1](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2346849/determinant-of-base-change-matrix-is-the-index), [2](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/65913/why-is-the-determinant-equal-to-the-index), [3](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/920870/explain-why-the-determinant-of-a-is-the-index-of-the-subring), [4](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/107630/computing-index-of-a-subgroup-of-a-free-abelian-group)

Comment: I was just reading the second link you sent me but I still have a doubt, why the index of $\Gamma=A$$\mathbb{Z}^k$ is the same as the index of $A´$$\mathbb{Z}^k$?